# Redirect an URL to another URL with Apache and WAMP?

Tags: apache-http-server

I was wondering how to make a simple redirection, I've got WAMP installed on my computer and I wish I could do that: When I go to `abc.com` it redirects to `xyz.com`. I did this in the `httpd.conf` file, but it isn't working.

It seems to work now, but only when I go to `localhost`. However, what I want is that when I go to `abc.com` it goes to `xyz.com`, and I can't do that.

Here is my conf :

```
   <VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerName abc.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.xyz.com/

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please add the non-working configuration you tried so that we have a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your intention, but you can make your configuration work by claiming that your computer actually **is** `abc.com`.

For this to do you need to edit your `hosts` file and add the following line:

```
abc.com 127.0.0.1
```

Right now in your configuration, your webbrowser asks a DNS server for the IP of `abc.com` and the DNS server replies with an **external** IP address. Due to this, your local server never sees the request so it never acts on it.

If you want this to work across your network you should consider using a HTTP proxy rather than a webserver.